# Question regarding Cauchy sequences and convergent sequences.

Tags: real-analysis

If convergent sequences are bounded and convergent sequences are Cauchy sequences, can't you conclude that Cauchy sequences are bounded? Can one make this conclusion just from the logic or is the proof necessary?

Comment: What kind of spaces are you considering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You logic is incorrect.

You correctly say "Convergent $\Rightarrow$ Bounded" and "Convergent $\Rightarrow$ Cauchy". You cannot use transitivity of implication to conclude "Cauchy $\Rightarrow$ Bounded" *unless*, as Mhenni hints, you are working in a complete space, in which case we also have "Cauchy $\Rightarrow$ Convergent" as well.

Comment: Oh okay, I haven't covered much of metric spaces.

Comment: Saying $X$ is $Y$ is different from saying $X \implies Y$, instead it's more like saying $ X \subseteq Y$. See Andreas' answer for instance.

Answer (score 1):

The logic you have in mind seems to be that, if all X's are Z and all X's are also Y, then all Y's are Z.  (In the case at hand, X is "convergent", Y is "Cauchy", and Z is "bounded".  This is, unfortunately, not a valid logical principle.  Consider, for example, the case where X is "dog", Y is "animal", and Z is "mammal".